Changing the Legend Title in a `ggpointdensity` Density Scatterplot
I have the following data and the following graph.
df <- data.frame(col1 = rnorm(1000, 0, 0.05), col2 = rnorm(1000, 0, 0.05))
ggplot(data = df, mapping = aes(x = col1, y = col2)) +
  geom_pointdensity() +
  scale_color_viridis()


To make a publication-quality figure, I'd like to change the legend title from "n_neighbors" to "Point Density". I've tried a couple things, but neither of them worked.
ggplot(data = df, mapping = aes(x = col1, y = col2)) +
  geom_pointdensity() +
  scale_color_viridis() +
  labs(fill = "Point Density")
ggplot(data = df, mapping = aes(x = col1, y = col2)) +
  geom_pointdensity() +
  scale_color_viridis() +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "Point Density"))

Is there a way to make this change?

The reason your attempts are failing is because you are changing the name of the fill scale, but the points are using the color scale.

You can change the legend title using the name argument in the scale_color_viridis() function:
library(viridis)
library(ggpointdensity)
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(col1 = rnorm(1000, 0, 0.05), col2 = rnorm(1000, 0, 0.05))
ggplot(data = df, mapping = aes(x = col1, y = col2)) +
  geom_pointdensity() +
  scale_color_viridis(name = "Point Density")


Alternatively, using the color argument in labs():
ggplot(data = df, mapping = aes(x = col1, y = col2)) +
  geom_pointdensity() +
  scale_color_viridis() +
  labs(color = "Point Density")

or in guides():
ggplot(data = df, mapping = aes(x = col1, y = col2)) +
  geom_pointdensity() +
  scale_color_viridis() +
  guides(color = guide_legend(title = "Point Density"))

The point color comes from the color argument, not fill which is why your original code didn't work.
